# How do I draw figure like this in Matlab?

Tags: excel, matlab-figure

I want to draw a figure similar to the figure below. Does anyone know how to do it?

What I have is a 5 by 10 matrix, with each element range in [0, 1].

Is this able to be done in matlab or should I used other tools like excel?

[image]

Comment: Did you have a look at the bar3() function in Matlab

Answer (score 0):

As suggested you can use `bar3`. Here is a quick example:

```
data = rand(5,10);
h = bar3(data);
set(h,'FaceAlpha',0.7)
view(-136,14)
```

[image: bar3]